# is the following set complete in $l_p$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

I'm not sure what is the correct term in English, but by 'complete set' I mean that  the span (of finite combinations) of the set is dense in the space.

I have to show for which p ($ 1\leq p <\infty $) the following is a complete set in the sequence space $ l_p $ :
$$\{ x_1=(1,-1,0,0,...) \\
x_2=(0,1,-1,0,0,...) \\
...\\
x_n=(0,...,0,1,-1,0,...)\\
...\}$$
(for $x_n$ the nth index is 1, followed by -1).

It is easy to show that it is true for p=2 by showing that the only sequence normal to each of these vectors is the zero sequence.

I have tried proving that it is not true for p other than 2 by showing that
$\|e_1-\Sigma c_kx_k\|_p$ is always greater than 1, for the unit vector $e_1=(1,0,0,...)$ and any constants $c_k$. i didn't manage to prove it, and I can't see why it would be different for p=2, which might say that my assumption is wrong.

I have seen this question with slight variations, in which the set becomes for example  $x_n=(0,...,0,1,\sqrt{1+1/n},0,...)$.

Comment: Note for $p=1$, each $x_i$ is in the kernal of the functional $(1,1,\ldots)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different way for $p>1$:

It's not to hard to show the linear span of the $x_i$ contains the vectors   $$y_n=(1,\underbrace{-1/n,-1/n,\ldots,-1/n}_{n\text{-terms}},0,\ldots).$$

Since, for $p>1$, we have $\Vert e_1-y_n\Vert_p =1/n^{1-1/p}\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$,  $e_1$ is in the closed linear span of the $x_i$. But then every $e_i$ is in the closed linear span of the $x_i$.

It follows that $\{x_i \mid i\in\Bbb N\}$ is dense in $\ell_p$, for $p>1$.

For $p=1$, see my comment above.

Comment: i see now why my assumption that the norm of this difference is always greater than 1 was wrong. it's a great example. i'm not sure that i understand your solution for p=1 though. $x_i$ is indeed in the kernel of that functional. oh, i see now that it contradicts the general method given in yurii's solution. thank you.

Comment: i can't however see directly (without that theorem) why being in the kernel of that functional says that it is not dense. is it easy to understand without proving the general theorem?

Comment: @dini $(1,1,\ldots)$ is zero at each $x_i$ and thus at each element of the linear span, $S$, of the $x_i$. Now if $x\in\overline S$, there is a sequence from $S$ that converges to $x$ in norm. By continuity it follows that $(1,1,\ldots)$ is zero at $x$.  (Of course, this is just the proof of one direction of the general theorem).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** try the similar idea as for $p=2.$ I.e. use the mapping $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:\ell_p\times\ell_q\to\mathbb C$ instead of the scalar product.

**Statement**: a vector subspace $F$ of a Banach space $E$ is dense in $E$ if and only if $\text{for every functional}\ f\in E'$ holds:

$$\text{the restriction}\ f|_F=0\ \text{if and only if}\ f=0\ \text{on}\ E$$

Comment: just to make sure - the mapping is the sum of the multiplication of the sequences' terms, without exponentiation? anyways, i see that the the restriction holds only for the zero sequence, so i guess it is dense in the spaces. thank you.

Comment: Yes, the mapping is $\langle(x_k),(y_k)\rangle=\sum_k x_ky_k.$